# How to run batch script on server which exists in different domain of your PC?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, telnet, psexec

I am trying to execute a batch file residing on some server which lie in different domain w.r.t my pc.

I tried:

1. PSExec -> but its persistently giving error:

   ```
   Couldn't access 192.168.238.74:
   The network path was not found.
   Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on 192.168.238.74.
   ```

   I have enable the admin$ share at both computers and I have also added the registry, using reg add "some text I don't remember" on cmd, but its still giving error.
2. I thought of telnet, but I don't know how to use that.

Please give some elegant solution to my problem. I am beginner here, so code with explanation will be very useful.

Also, I have the userid and password of servers.

Comment: just a shot in the dark, and maybe this only works for logins, but I have this note from when I got a different error with psexec "Open the Control Panel.
In Control Panel, double-click Administrative Tools, and then click Local Security Policy.
In Local Security Settings, double-click Local Policies, double-click Audit Policy, and then click the events that you want to audit.

To view the resulting audit events, start Event Viewer and choose Windows Logs -> Security."    But that aside. Can you do \\comp\c$? or \\comp\C ? and consider temporarily disabling the windows firewall

Comment: @rocko Have you tested your network connection? Maybe there's a firewall? Try accessing that share manually.